# Coloring man pages doesn't work anymore?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, colors, man, terminal-emulator

I've had this for more than 3 years in my bashrc:

```bash
man() {
    LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[01;31m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\e[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\e[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\e[01;44;33m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\e[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[01;32m' \
    command man "$@"
}
```

I don't remember where I picked it from, but it is for coloring `man` pages.

The strange thing is that now my `man` pages are not colored anymore since a short time (days/months?) on my personal system, which is

- up-to-date ArchLinux,
- GNU bash 5.1.16(1)-release),
- less 633 (PCRE2 regular expressions) Copyright (C) 1984-2023  Mark Nudelman
- `grep LESS_TERMCAP /usr/bin/less` reports that it binary matches

The stranger thing is that on another system,

- Debian 11,
- GNU bash 5.1.4(1)-release
- less 551 (GNU regular expressions) Copyright (C) 1984-2019  Mark Nudelman
- `grep LESS_TERMCAP /usr/bin/less` reports that it binary matches

coloring in `man` pages is still working, and it is removed if I comment out the snippet above.

Any clues to what could be going on?

---

[I know there are other ways](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Color_output_in_console#man), but since I *know* the solution above worked, I'm curious to know what happened.

Comment: What is the output of `less --version` on your Arch, vs. on the other system? If you run `grep LESS_TERMCAP /usr/bin/less`, does it report "binary file matches", or not?

Comment: @telcoM, updated.

Comment: Can't reproduce with `less 633 (PCRE2 regular expressions)`/`bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release`/`zsh 5.9 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` and Terminator or GNOME Console (`TERM=xterm-256color`) on Arch Linux. Manpages show colouring (red and green)

Comment: What are the values set for $MANPAGER and $PAGER ?

Comment: $MANOPT might also be relevant. The default settings of `man` might be documented in comments of `/etc/manpath.config`; also `~/.manpath` might be overriding the defaults if it exists.

Comment: @muru and @telcoM, `echo ${MANPAGER-0}${PAGER-0}${MANOPT-0}` prints `000`. And I don't have `~/.manpath` or `/etc/manpath.config` files.

Comment: Very strange. Unlike @muru, I can reproduce with `less 633 (PCRE2 regular expressions)`/`bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release`/`TERM=xterm-256color` and Terminator on my Arch Linux, and could also reproduce (i.e. got no colors) on an Ubuntu system I tried (all versions the same except `less 590 (GNU regular expressions)`).

Comment: After launching man, please ensure it is actually using less as pager from a ps output.

Comment: @MC68020, I started `bash`, executed `man cat`, pressed Ctrl+Z, and then executed `ps`, getting 4 entries, `bash`, `man`, `less`, `ps`.

Comment: @terdon hmm, I tried again on an Arch Linux ARM running on a Raspberry Pi, over JuiceSSH (Android SSH client) and I still get colours. (Same version of `less`). But I think see why now.

Comment: I have `GROFF_NO_SGR=1` set on all my Linux systems.

Comment: Ah! Yes, @muru, with that set, I get colors. Sounds like you have an answer!

Comment: @terdon, for me too, but I've never set `GROFF_NO_SGR=1` before... :/

Comment: @Enlico this started affecting me on Arch a couple months or so ago

Comment: Ah: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/79053

Comment: @muru, I thought you could not reproduce it! :/

Comment: Regardless, is my question really a duplicate of that???

Comment: Well, I did have `GROFF_NO_SGR` already set since a few weeks now, and my original symptoms were slightly different (I use Vim for my manpager). Regardless, the problem is the same and the current solution is also the same.

Comment: @Enlico it seems to be a pretty exact duplicate, why would it not be? The answer there gives a solution and links to the relevant bug. Is there something else missing? Along with https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/79053, which muru posted above, we seem to have the whole story.

Comment: @terdon, I guess I need to read them both.

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu without `GROFF_NO_SGR=1`.  This is due to some patch being removed that adds a `-c` command line option to `nroff` or something. The bug referenced in the duplicate question dated 2013.